# Delphi TWebbrowser - Read POST data?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

When i navigate to a site with flash content using TWebbrowser, and this flash content has a button which sends a HTTP POST message to a server when I click on it... how can I get the sent POST data (body+header) and the answer from the server?

Currently I'm using an external application (Fiddler) for grabbing this data, but I want to do this directly in my Delphi application with TWebbrowser.

Comment: The Flash application's POST data never hits your application code so you can't intercept it except with a HTTP proxy

Comment: @mjn or a packet capture library, like libpcap

Comment: bad news for me. but thanks! I will have a look at libpcap